# Vuetify Table sortable column is not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

[image]

I have these vuetify table, this is how I configure the header

```
         headers: [
            {
                text: 'Name',
                align: 'start',
                sortable: false,
                value: 'name',
                width: '20%'
            },
            { text: 'Link Count', value: 'count', width: '10%', sortable: true },
            { text: 'URL', value: 'details', width: '50%' },
            { text: 'Actions', value: 'id', width: '20%' }
        ]
```

---

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="items" :search="search">
    ...
    <template v-slot:item.count="{ item }">
        {{ item.details.length }}
    </template>
    ...
```

As you can see I have `sortable: true` for **Link Count** column.

Some how it is not working...

How can I debug this further ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `<v-data-table>` comes with a sortable functionality for all the columns. By your question what I understood if that by default you want `count` column sorted in ascending/descending order when grid loads.

If Yes, You can achieve that by using [external-sorting](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#external-sorting) feature of data grid.

Working demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      sortBy: 'count',
      sortDesc: false,
      headers: [
            {
                text: 'Name',
                align: 'start',
                value: 'name',
                width: '20%'
            },
            { text: 'Link Count', value: 'count', width: '10%' },
            { text: 'URL', value: 'details', width: '50%' },
            { text: 'Actions', value: 'id', width: '20%' }
        ],
      items: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          count: 159,
          details: 'Detail 1',
          id: 24
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          count: 237,
          details: 'Detail 2',
          id: 37
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          count: 262,
          details: 'Detail 3',
          id: 23
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          count: 305,
          details: 'Detail 4',
          id: 67
        }
      ],
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <div>
      <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
        :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
        class="elevation-1"
      ></v-data-table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Please let me know if my understanding is not correct or any further changes required as per the requirement.

Comment: Thanks Rohit for always helping me and shared the working demo.

Comment: @code-8 I am glad that it helps you. Can you please accept this answer so that it will be helpful for other developers as well.

Answer (score 1):

You set up your 'Link Count' column to `count` field and use `item.count` slot in component, but internal table sorter has no idea what is this `count` field.

If you are sure that your `details` column will never has specific values like **null**, **undefined**, etc, you can change your code this way:

```js
...
{ text: 'Link Count', value: 'details.length', width: '10%', sortable: true},
...
<template v-slot:item.details.length="{ item }">
  {{ item.details.length }}
</template>
...
```

(Or you don't even need to override this slot)

Otherwise, if you care about null/undefined, it'd be better to create *computed* property with your current data plus additional calculated `count` column, and use it instead of `items` in component. This way, for example:

```js
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="computedDesserts"
  :items-per-page="5"
></v-data-table>
...
data () {
  return {
    headers: [
      { text: 'Dessert (100g serving)', value: 'name'},
      { text: 'Dessert Count', value: 'count' },
      ...
    ],
    desserts: [
      { name: 'Frozen Yogurt', calories: 159, ... },
      ...
    ],
  }
},
computed: {
  computedDesserts() {
    return this.desserts.map(item => {
      return { ...item, count: this.isValidString(item.name) ? item.name.length : 0 }
    });
  }
},
methods: {
  isValidString(val) {
    return typeof val === 'string'; //Or you can use your own condition
  }
}
```

CodePen demo with computed props [is available here](https://codepen.io/betanet/pen/vYdBgyV).

Comment: Alex, thank-you very much for your explanation of what I did wrong. 

Comment: Can you please show me how to do a null check in a computed property ?

Comment: @code-8, just updated my answer, you can check demo at CodePen